# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer"

Tags: android, mopub, millennial-media

I recently moved to MoPub and it all appears to be working well except for I have started getting this exception saying that `com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer` can not be found. I looked and it isn't on the Millennial jar (I just got the latest from their site). Also my AndroidManifest mentions that class and Android Studio also says it can't be found.

This is what I have there:

```
<activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
<activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
```

On Android Studio the VideoPlayer part is red.

This is the exception I got:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" on path: /data/app/mypackage-1.apk
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" on path: /data/app/mypackage-1.apk
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the latest Millennial Media [documentation](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-SDK/AndroidSDKInstall.html), it looks like

> com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer

isn't included.  This may be an update that needs to be made.

Alice